# Error in Importing Maven Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I'm facing an error while trying to import a Maven Java project in Eclipse.
I think this problem is due to the operating system because I moved from Windows to Ubuntu. I am getting the error below :

> An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
>   org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/OS

Comment: When you import a Maven Java Project in Eclipse which comes from windows you have the problem? Or the same in Ubuntu? Or only from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: Line endings? Open your POM in a text editor like vi. If you see funny little ^Ms at the end of each line, you'll need to convert those Windows line endings to unix.

Answer (score 0):

File->Import->Archival file and select exported file from Windows.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/144754/how-do-i-transfer-an-eclipse-project-from-windows-to-ubuntu

Comment: this is the classic method to import projects but I want to import it using Maven